# Использование данных из файла php

Tags: php

Добрый день. Стоит вот такая интересная и странная задача. На сайте aaa.com находится файл code.txt он открыт для чтения. Вопрос, можно ли с сайта bbb.ru открыть этот файл и считать из него содержимое. Причем не просто считать, а в этом файле есть код, который в результате должен быть выполнен на bbb.ru. Тоесть мы подключаемся к сайту aaa.com, получаем там код и выполняем его на сайте bbb.ru.
Вопрос следующий, реально ли реализовать подобное силами PHP?

Comment: считываете файл в переменную и запускаете  eval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP по силам выполнить любой поток байтов. Это его ключевая особенность: всё, что вне тегов `<?php` `?>` отправляется на вывод, а всё что внутри — исполняется. Пустить код скрипта на выход не исполняя тоже можно: достаточно просто прочитать файл и вывести. Например через readfile().

Надеюсь вы не собираетесь разрешать инклудить URL? Это был бы выстрел в собственную ногу.

Comment: Не не не, интересен сам механизм.